# Read from database Entity Framework Context

Tags: sql, entity-framework, dbcontext

I use an EF `DbContext` and have the following code to read users from a SQL table with specific statuses:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsersAsync(bool includeFutureUsers, params UserStatus[] statusFilters)
{
        IQueryable<User> query = _context.Users;

        if (statusFilters.Contains(User.All))
        {
            if (!includeFutureUsers)
            {
                DateTime currentUtcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                query = query.Where(user => user.JoinDate <= currentUtcTime);
            }

            return await query.ToListAsync();
        }           

        if (!includeFutureJobs)
        {
            DateTime currentUtcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            query = query.Where(user => user.JoinDate <= currentUtcTime); ----> LINE X
        }

        var users = await query.ToListAsync();

        var filteredUsers = users.Where(user => statusFilters.Contains((User)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserStatus), user.Status)));

        return filteredUsers;
    }
}

public enum UserStatus
{
    All = 0,
    Young = 1,
    Adult = 2,
    Men = 3,
    Women = 4,
    Toddler = 5
}

public class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }

    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

As you see here, `UserStatus` is of type `Enum` and `User.Status` is of type string.

Is it possible to update line X to get users with `Status` included in `statusFilters`?

I tried:

```
query = query.Where(user => user.JoinDate <= currentUtcTime && 
                            statusFilters.Contains((User)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserStatus), user.Status)));
```

But that throws an error

> Could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the status is stored as a String in the database / User Entity then in the Linq query, use strings for the desired statues rather than trying to convert the data. Don't `ToList` the users prior to filtering, this will load *all* users with only whatever filtering you've done before the `ToList` call.

```
var statuses = statusFilters.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();

var filteredUsers = await query
    .Where(user => statuses.Contains(user.Status))
    .ToListAsync();
return filteredUsers;
```